# select a specific word from a field in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have created the following table.

```
create table MYTABLE (address text);
```

I have inserted the the following row in my table.

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES('Smartlink House, Plot # 5, 
Kurla-Bandra Complex Road,
Tel : +xxxxxxxx
Email : helpdesk@digisol.com');
```

now, I want to fetch email and Tel no: from the above row.
Please don't tell to insert email and tel no in separate column as I have already created the database in the above manner.

Comment: I guess a regular expression would be your best option, or do the extraction in whatever language you're consuming the query in. The correct answer is of course to change your database design as it's currently wrong

Comment: Why did you not create seperate columns for email and tel?

Comment: I have already told you that I have created the database and it has 1000s of line and it is not possible to change the database.

Comment: Maybe your question should be how can I change my database without losing data.

Comment: No, it _is_ possible, you've just ruled it out as an option for some unknown reason

Comment: yup, that could have been one of the question but it is not.

Comment: So you're asking a bunch of programmers to tell you how to do something that you know is wrong and should be changed? I don't think you're going to get an answer that satisfies you here, id imagine people will tell you to do this properly, or work out the string matching yourself

Comment: And what did you try to get this information out of your badly designed table?

Comment: If you guys don't know how to solve the question please stop giving negative points as negative means "This question doesn't show any research" though in reality this question is of much research

Comment: This question shows precisely zero effort to solve the problem - you have entered a specification for a problem you want to fix, you haven't described what you've tried to fix it yourself. So research == 0 here, hence the downvotes. If you don't want to be told 'don't do it that way, do it properly', a Q+A site frequented by professional programmers is not the right place for you to ask

Comment: The only solution : fire the guy that designed that table, and hire a secretary that will type the data in a well designed table.

Comment: Stop giving such answers "hire a secretary". I know you guys don't know how to tackel this question and therefore you are giving negative points to the question........But let me tell you I have just asked my friend and he has told me the solution....without hiring a secretary huhh

Comment: Just because you don't like or understand the advice yours being given, does not make it wrong. I urge you to remember this question a year from now when you've learned more about programming. Then you'll understand where your misconceptions are, and you'll concede that you should have re-designed your table rather than hacking a way around the problem

Comment: Wow, he's really skilled your friend. But don't forget to fire that guy !

Comment: I know that I have created the database in a wrong way...and I know it today only as such misconception does not require a year to understand but I was just asking for the solution

Comment: The solution is to fix what you've broken - but you're not interested in that, you want a quick hack that will (on the surface) bandage the problem for now. That's a bad practice, and something you will endeavour to avoid with more experience. I don't say this to insult you or anything like that, it's just a simple fact

Comment: @LorenzMeyer I know he is very skilled...as he has found the solution which you really don't know

Comment: @Clive lets come to your point of view, can you tell me how to change the database and separate the field in the database having 1000s of line

Comment: Sure - write a script to pull out the old data (your friend has apparently already told you how to do this), insert it into a new table with the proper columns, delete the old table, rename the new table as the old. Done :)

Comment: @Clive sorry he is not as skilled as you as he hasn't told me about the script, he has just told me a simple solution

Comment: I get the impression you feel like you're under attack a bit with the barrage of 'don't do that' comments - we're really not trying to do that. We're saying "Woah! Been there before my friend, this doesn't end well. Back up and redesign your table or this data is going to cause you headaches forever more". It's great that you have a solution, but just keep the objections in the back of your mind for next time. This is how we all learn - by doing it wrong

Comment: @clive thanx for understanding me...In future I will try to make the database proper instead of arguing for my own mistake.

Comment: @toadalskiii I'm happy you finally understood the point. Maybe my comment was a little too sharp...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install the [lib_mysqludf_preg](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg) MySQL UDF

```
SET @telRegEx= "/(?<=Tel : ).*/i";
SET @emailRegEx= "/(?<=Email : ).*/i";

SELECT 
    PREG_CAPTURE(@telRegEx, address_text) as tel,
    PREG_CAPTURE(@emailRegEx, address_text) as email
FROM 
    MYTABLE
```

ps: You have to find a way to change your table structure, it's a very ugly way to save data in a database.

Answer (score 1):

create another table named my_table1 with 'n' numbers of column but create two column with same data type as tel_no and email from my_table. Then follow the sample code,

insert into my_table1 (tel_no1, email1) as select (tel_no,email) from my_table

Comment: Please read the question before answering